# Infragistics Netadvantage Window Forms "Failed to create component"

Tags: exception, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics Netadvantage Windows Forms 11.2 Version 2135.  I've got two different virtual machines (code migration). On the first VM I can use the designer on the second VM I get an error when adding a control to a view:

```
Failed to create component 'AnimateControl'.
```

My license file looks like this:

Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraDateTimeEditor, 
Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinEditors.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.2050, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb
Infragistics.Win.UltraWinSchedule.UltraCalendarCombo, Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinSchedule.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.2050, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb
Infragistics.Win.UltraWinExplorerBar.UltraExplorerBar, Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinExplorerBar.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.2050, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb
Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.UltraToolbarsManager, Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinToolbars.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.2050, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb

and so on...

The assemblies for which are listed in license file are stored in gac.

When creating an empty project I can use the infragtistics controls.

What can I do to use the designer?

Answer (score 0):

The following thread shows the answer.

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/86198.aspx

My CLR4-Assemblies were only installed in GAC. I moved them to my project folder and it worked.